# SELECT returning rows when executed from SQL client but none when executed from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT sum(x), sum(y)
FROM stats s1
WHERE fk_id = :id
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT
  FROM stats s2
  WHERE s2.fk_id = s1.fk_id
  AND s2.datetime::date = (now() - '1 day'::interval)::date
)
```

The second condition ensures that there are stats from yesterday. Otherwise it returns no results.

When I execute it from a SQL client (i.e. DBeaver), it returns 1 row as expected, e.g. `12.3, 45.6`. When I execute the query from SQLAlchemy, i.e. `session.execute(query, {"id": id}).first()`, it returns `(None, None)`. Same query, same database, same id.

I tried running it from SQLAlchemy **without the `EXISTS` condition**, and in this case, it returns 1 row. So it's something related to the second condition when executed from different places.

Why does the `EXISTS` condition return `TRUE` when executed from a SQL client but `FALSE` from SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 0):

You must `SELECT` something, even in a subquery, even if it makes no sense:

---

```
SELECT SUM(s1.x), SUM(s1.y)
FROM stats s1
WHERE s1.fk_id = :id
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 'OMG!' -- <<-- HERE
  FROM stats s2
  WHERE s2.fk_id =  s1.fk_id
  AND s2.datetime::date = (now() - '1 day'::interval)::date
  )
  ;
```